# Using XAML binding how can I visually alert users that a tab contains data (in child controls)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

My WPF TabControl contains multiple TabItems. **I want to visually alert users that data exists on a tab**. Currently users have to click each tab to be sure nothing important was overlooked. Each tab represents a step (with instructions) of a multi-step workflow. Each workflow contains a random combination of steps (some steps may be skipped). I'd like tabs to change color or otherwise make it clear that one or more of it's child controls contain instructions.

**What binding syntax could I add** to either the parent TabControl or the child controls (typically TextBoxes) **to achieve this goal?** I'd like to minimize repetitive code and use a generic Style or DataTrigger that could be added to the resources section of the Window or App. A challenge is that the control with data may live in a second TabControl within the parent tab so there is not always a direct parent/child relationship.

I sense that my user interface could be redesigned and improved. I'd welcome suggestions along with your answer to my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define the tabs in your TabControl? Do you databind the TabControl to a collection of step data objects and use data templates or do you specify each tab in XAML?

Comment: I specify each tab in xaml (not dynamically). The underlying single table contains a set of fields for step A which belong on tab A, then fields for step B belonging on tab B, etc. I'm using Entity Framework 4 and binding directly to the object context (entity set). Each tab contains a UserControl that inherits its DataContext from the parent Window's CollectionViewSource (the cvs.source is the entity representing my database table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I alert users a tab has NO data by modifying the TabItem Header (that's the text on top). If no data exists I set the Foreground color to Gray so it appears disabled but is still clickable allowing data to be added. In addition I append the word "Blank" to the text. **Ultimately tabs with no data have a grayed out header which reads "Tab 1 Blank", "Tab 2 Blank" etc.**

Details:

I use two binding statements (for the Header and Foreground):

```
<TabItem x:Name="StepOneTabItem" 
 Header="{Binding StepOneDataExistsText}" 
 Foreground="{Binding Path=StepOneDataExistsText, 
     Converter={StaticResource tabForegroundGrayWhenBlankConverter}}">
```

Both Bindings make use of the property StepOneDataExistsText which I created on my DataContext. That property is simply a string set conditionally. When bound to the Header it displays either "Tab 1" or "Tab 1 Blank". The same property bound to Foreground uses a Converter to return either a Gray or Black SolidColorBrush (Gray when "Blank" is at the end of StepOneDataExistsText).

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush))]
public class TabForegroundGrayWhenBlankConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
       string passedInTextValue = (string)value;

       if (passedInTextValue.ToUpper().Contains("BLANK"))
       {
           return new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Gray);
       }
       else
       {
           return new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Black);
       }
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
       return null; 
   }
```

}

Initially I attempted to change the Background color of the TabItem but ran into difficulties [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861532/wpf4-in-code-behind-how-can-i-override-tabitem-colors-set-by-an-application-wide).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a data template or style template to achieve this.  Unfortunately my WPF and XAML is rusty so I can't offer code.  But templates are were you want to look.

Whoops should have finished reading the post.

So you want to preload the data? Assuming you are using some MVVM framework you could have your controller load the data and send a message to the form that contains and renders the tab.

Comment: This is a simple forms over data app. It uses WPF and bound controls. The DataContext is a CollectionViewSource in the Window.Resources section. The CVS.source is set to an Entity Framework ObjectContext (EntitySet) when the user selects a data filter. This is a small app created without MVVM so it is entirely XAML, entities and code behind.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the `ControlTemplate` of [`TabItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752032%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and use `DataTriggers` from view model boolean to trigger `border` colors.

**Edit**: A very minimal example, uses the same flag for all tabs, doesn't turn off when the user selects it, but you will get the idea. The key is the `MultiDataTrigger` in the template.

```
<Window x:Class="TabControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush> 

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#888" /> 
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" /> 
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#EEE" /> 
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" /> 
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border 
            Name="Border"
            Margin="0,0,-4,0" 
            Background="{StaticResource LightBrush}"
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" 
            BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
            CornerRadius="2,12,0,0" >
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              ContentSource="Header"
              Margin="12,2,12,2"
              RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding HasNewData}" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="False"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger>                             
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Header 1"/>
            <TabItem Header="Header 2"/>
            <TabItem Header="Header 3"/>
            <TabItem Header="Header 4"/>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public bool HasNewData { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.HasNewData = true;
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is quite helpful. Here's what I see happen...tabs NOT selected are red. When I change the MultiDataTrigger.Condition for IsSelected to Value=True then just the selected tab is red. Great! Now I need help changing the HasNewData property to something like ChildControlsHaveData. I want tabs to turn red when any bound textbox within the tab contains data. The tab should NOT be red if all bound controls on the tab are null or empty. Any suggestions? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I would implement `ChildControlsHaveData` to be a derived property of all the textbox values something like !String.IsNullOrEmpty(text1) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(text2) and raise property changed notification on ChildControlsHaveData property on all textbox viewmodel string setters.

Comment: Hmm. It seems I need to create a different trigger on each tab, plus a different property for each tab to bind to. Tab A would be bound to TabAControlsHaveData, tab B would be bound to TabBControlsHaveData etc. This is less elegant than I'd like but it will get the job done.